# Не могу использовать QMap<Key, T>::iterator как параметр другого шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Не пойму почему

Есть шаблон класса:

```
template <class Key, class T, class IteratorKey>
class Container : public IContainer<Key, T>
{
//...
};
```

Так НЕ работает:

```
template <class Key, class T>
class MemoryContainer : public Container<Key, T, QMap<Key, T>::iterator>
{
//    ...
};
```

Пишет:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for 'template<class Key, class T, class IteratorKey> class Container'
 class MemoryContainer : public Container<Key, T, QMap<Key, T>::iterator>


                                                               ^
```

---

**Так работает:**

```
template <class Key, class T>
class MemoryContainer : public Container<Key, T, QMap<int, int>::iterator>
{
//    ...
};
```

**И даже так работает:**

```
template <class Key, class T>
class MemoryContainer : public Container<Key, T, QMap<Key, T>>
{
//    ...
};
```

**Почему же так НЕ работает???**

```
template <class Key, class T>
class MemoryContainer : public Container<Key, T, QMap<Key, T>::iterator>
{
//    ...
};
```

Comment: Напишите typename QMap<Key, T>::iterator в качестве третьего шаблонного аргумента.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишите

```
template <class Key, class T>
class MemoryContainer : public Container<Key, T, typename QMap<Key, T>::iterator>
{
//    ...
};
```

Comment: Спасибо! Хотелось бы еще понять, почему без этого не работало, а с этим заработало. Почему, например, с `QMap<Key, T>` `typename` не требуется

Comment: @asianirish Это так называемые зависимые имена, то есть имена, зависящие от специализации шаблонного класса.

Comment: Да, прочитал, стало понятно: http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2006/08/typename.html

Comment: @asianirish  O'k. :)